# What do skill boosting affixes affect and what they don't?

Tags: diablo-iii

Some skills, when combined with a particular rune, grant a secondary effect like Demon Hunter [Sentry - Spitfire Turret](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/sentry) launching rockets or Crusader [Punish - Roar](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/crusader/active/punish) exploding in flames upon blocking or Barbarian [Whirlwind - Dust Devils](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/barbarian/active/whirlwind) launching tornadoes while whirlwinding and so on.

1. When you have an item that boosts a certain skill damage, does this
   also boost the secondary rune effect? (tornado, rocket,
   explosion...etc?)
2. When you have an item/set-bonus that actually triggers a skill
   without you using it like the Demon Hunter [Embodiment of the Marauder](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/marauders-spines) set that causes [Sentry](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/sentry)
   to use hatred spenders or the Barbarian [Bul-Kathos's Oath](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/bulkathoss-solemn-vow) that triggers a
   whirlwind on its own, do these "item" triggered skills benefit from
   the skill boosting affixes?

Comment: afaik the bul katho's whirlwind effect is treated like a proc, its not the same as the whirlwind skill so no it won't be boosted in that case. The rest of it should be affected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is, skill boosting affixes will boost secondary effects from those runes as well.

For instance, an affix that boosts punish will also boost the damage caused by the fire explosion when blocking (roar rune).  And whirlwind skill boost will cause the tornados to do more damage.

The only thing I'm not sure of is whether or not having a skill boosting your hatred spender (such as cluster arrows) will boost the CA being cast by the sentry.  I suspect that damage is still tied to your sentry skill, so if you had sentry affix gear it'll boost the damage.

Comment: Anecdotal evidence regarding sentries from what I've seen: Equipment that boosts sentry damage will affect the hatred spenders of your sentry.  Equipment that boosts other spenders will not affect the damage your sentry does when using those spenders.

Comment: @Doc Thanks, that's pretty much from what I'v eseen too, but I have no hard evidence to back that up with.